# groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException: Not Found

Tags: java, rest, groovy, automated-tests

I am writing tests for restful webservices that I have created. The tests were running fine until the package names changed. Now when I try to call the webservice I get a 404. This test is in groovy, but the actual webservice is in java.

```
RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient(APPURL);
def HttpResponseDecorator result =      restClient.post(path:"/traffic/trackParticipation",
                                headers: [accept: 'application/json'],
                                contentType: ContentType.JSON,
                                body: trackingRequest
        )
```

The trackingRequest is as follows :

```
  {"psid":"MDBmOd1xGjkkx94esSUpzQ**","participationType":"game","gameParticipationId":"1","surveyParticipationId":"1","timeSpent":"300","timestamp":"2013-05-24 10:30:40"}
```

This same json works with other requests. Like the ones called from Firefox.

If I call the same service from any other client such as firefox, it works fine. I have cleaned all the tmp files on the server as well as from the target. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

The error I get is

```
    groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException: Not Found
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:500)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.post(RESTClient.java:140)
    .....
    Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:143)
at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
at net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper.parseText(JsonSlurper.java:80)
at net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper.parse(JsonSlurper.java:76)
at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseJSON(ParserRegistry.java:282)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.parseResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:561)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
... 2 more
```

Thanks

Comment: How does `trackingRequest` json look like?

Comment: Updated the question with the tracking request.

Comment: When you say package names changed, you mean the POST url has been modified or the package name in the producer side has been modified? I wanted to get a clear picture before hopping into the problem? Can you also show the credentials (like URL) you used testing from browser?

Comment: I am not using credentials to call the web service. The names of the packages that these files resided in. The URL has stayed the same. nothing in the way it was called has changed. The url that I used to test is localhost:8080//traffic/trackParticipation. Hope that helps.